# boto3 dynamodb aggregation query2

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a table in DynamoDB in the below format: I am pulling the data from this table using boto3 and want to create a new table basis user input ( DeviceId, Date Range).This table will have sensortype wise data - Max,min and avg grouped by minute.

Iam making some basic error which is causing the aggregation to fall apart..not able to figure it out.This is causing the entire aggregation to fail.. I want to group by DeviceId, then SensorType and then aggregate on Minutes .

[Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfFaj.jpg)

```
items_by_minute = itertools.groupby(col, key=lambda x: (x["SensorDataType"],x["CurrentTime"][:16]))


for minute, items in items_by_minute:
        values_per_minute = [item["SensorValue"] for item in items]

        avg = statistics.mean(values_per_minute)
        avg = round (avg,2)
        min_value = min(values_per_minute)
        max_value = max(values_per_minute)

        print(f" Stype: {minute[0]}/ Minute: {minute[1]}/ Average {avg} / Min {min_value} / Max {max_value}")
```

Comment: @Maurice Pls help..

Comment: When you say the aggregation is failing, do you mean that you are getting an error?  Or do you mean that the numbers aren't correct?  How it is failing?

Comment: @SethGeoghegan Instead of Minute Level aggregation, I get the output as below `#output MType: ('HeartRate', '2021-03-13 14:50')/ Average 83.20 / Min 61 / Max 105
 MType: ('Temperature', '2021-03-13 14:50')/ Average 98.30 / Min 98.3 / Max 98.3
 MType: ('SPO2', '2021-03-13 14:50')/ Average 91.00 / Min 91 / Max 91
 MType: ('HeartRate', '2021-03-13 14:50')/ Average 85.07 / Min 64 / Max 99
 MType: ('SPO2', '2021-03-13 14:50')/ Average 86.00 / Min 86 / Max 86
 MType: ('HeartRate', '2021-03-13 14:50')/ Average 81.15 / Min 66 / Max 89
`